# Why is the raster data blank in geoserver？

Tags: geoserver, geomesa

I want to publish raster data using geoserver and geomesa, but I published the data according to the tutorial was empty. I don't know what went wrong.

This is for a new Linux server, running geoserver-2.14.4, hadoop-2.7.1 , accumulo-1.9.2,.geomesa-accumulo_2.11-2.3.0 and zookeeper-3.4.9.

The  tutorial  url: https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geomesa-raster.html

Screenshots:

- [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itUA8.png)
- [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIaZ9.png)
- [Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZU0V.png)

Comment: Please avoid overusing tags. Tags that are only marginally related to your issue (such as 'raster' and 'accumulo') should not be used. Tags are used by others to help identify and answer questions pertaining to their expertise, so you should take care to ensure they are strongly relevant. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging for more information about tagging.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Command-Line that is not correct to ingest data ,the Command-Line is "geomesa-accumulo ingest-raster -u root -p root -t natearth -f "/mnt/data/NE1_HR_LC_SR_W/1/" -F geotiff",it need to be replace by  "geomesa-accumulo ingest-raster -u root -p root -t natearth -f "/mnt/data/NE1_HR_LC_SR_W/1/" -F tif"